# Como puedo agrupar una lista de arreglos por un Id en C#?

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist

Hola me preguntaba si alguien me puede orientar para lo siguiente. en mi código estoy obteniendo una lista de arreglos de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[{id = 3,nombre= "cccc",valor=34555},{id= 7,nombre="bbbb",valor=98999},{id=3,nombre="ssss",valor=15877}];
```

Quiero saber como puedo agrupar u ordenar la lista al encontrar coincidencia en el id. Es decir que mis datos queden de la siguiente manera. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

[image: Quiero saber como puedo agrupar u ordenar la lista al encontrar coincidencia en el id. Es decir que mis datos queden de la siguiente manera.]

```
[[{id = 3,nombre= "cccc",valor=34555},{id=3,nombre="ssss",valor=15877}],[{id= 7,nombre="bbbb",valor=98999}]];
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon tu código como texto

Comment: Lo que te pide Japv es importante, ya que no todos querrán transcribir tu código para poder ayudarte. Aquí se exponen otros motivos detras de dicho pedido: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: Hola comprendo, ya realicé la edicion, estoy pendiente a sus comentarios, gracias.

Comment: Juan, los elementos que estan dentro de esa lista de que tipo son, es una clase definida por ti?

Comment: Esos datos que están ahí, son el resultado de una consulta que hago a una db he iterando la consulta me queda una lista del estilo que les indico en la primera imagen, sin embargo me gustaría agrupar los datos por el id. y si, la lista es creada apartir de un modelo con esos parametros definidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de **Linq**:

```
var listaAgrupada = from l in lista 
                    group l by l.id into grupo
                    select new {
                                  Id = grupo.Key,
                                  IdGrupos = grupo
                               };
```

En esta consulta utilizamos la **claúsula group by** de **Linq** para agrupar la lista por la **propiedad id**.

Para recorrer la agrupación obtenida hacemos lo siguiente:

```
foreach (var l in listaAgrupada)
{
   Console.WriteLine(l.Id);
   
   foreach (var g in l.IdGrupos)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("  " + g.Nombre);
      Console.WriteLine("  " + g.Valor);
   }
}
```

Hacemos dos **foreach**, donde el primer **foreach** recorrerá e imprimirá los **id** o **llaves** de cada grupo obtenido, mientras el segundo **foreach** recorrerá por cada **id** o **llave** de grupo todos los elementos que tienen en común el mismo **id**, imprimiendo la **propiedad Nombre** y la **propiedad Valor** por cada objeto.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, queria preguntar si es posible que la **listaAgrupada** se cree bajo un modelo que ya tengo definido, Puede ser el mismo que el de la lista del modelo?

Comment: @JuanVega dame mas detalle, explica mejor lo que quieres

Comment: Mi función es esta: **public async Task<List<QualityCheckMinorUnitDetails>>**. Como ves, tengo que retornar una lista de tipo **QualityCheckMinorUnitDetails** que es un modelo que tengo previamente creado, esposible que a la hora de retornar la lista **listaAgrupada** sea del mismo modelo que requiere la función?

Comment: Si, es posible, lo único que esa clase tendría que tener dos propiedades(no necesariamente con el mismo nombre), el id que seria un entero y la propiedad IdGrupos que es una lista donde cada objeto de esta lista tendría otras dos propiedades(no necesariamente con el mismo nombre) que serian el nombre y el valor

Comment: O sea la clase definida por ti debe tener los mismos campos y del mismo tipo que el tipo que se guarda en la variable listaAgrupada